# How to create a database in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm new with this program and with Ubuntu. I want to learn how to use MySQL. Can you tell me how to create a database with a table in it and how to write values in that table?

Comment: I'd suggest you start with [MySQL WorkBench GUI](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-installing-linux.html), and watch  this tutorial [How to create database and tables in MySql Workbench 6.3 for beginners](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q92CJTIAiQM). WorkBench is available for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [MySQL For Absolute Beginners](http://www.elated.com/articles/mysql-for-absolute-beginners/)

This will show you the create database command, the create table command, how to insert data into the table, and how to query the data.

It provides Ubuntu information as well.